# Which Blog Client for Windows/Linux has the best support for backing/restoring your posts?

Tags: backup

I started using Akeeba Remote Control for Joomla and was really impressed with it.  When I went to look for something similar for Wordpress, I found these Weblog clients.

Which one is the best for backing/restoring up your content? 
(Existing and content that you add to the blog via the Weblog client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really direct answer to your question, but I think complete (database plus files) backup/restore is more comprehensive and important.

Content backup is only content. Database is all of your blog, which can help you go from nuked database back to normal in no time (speaking from sad practical experience, that would be much more sad without complete database backup).

Would you like to keep your question about clients alone or expand it to backup/resotre in general (it's marked as community wiki so I am trying to establish scope) ?

Comment: Well I know about the FTP backups, and I know about backing up your database, but is there an all in one solution that'll take it from two steps down to one?

Comment: I think there are some plugins that will do both, but I have these backups set up separately so no experience with examples of combined backup.

Answer (score 1):

Windows live writer is best for this. You can download it freely from mss site. It supports draft and xml rpm. Dont forget to enable it from dashboard